# Best way to manage SQL Server on developer, test, staging, and production environments through Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I've read an article on [MS Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx) and on here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434312/how-can-i-manage-sql-permissions-between-development-and-production) and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388914/how-to-properly-manage-database-deployment-with-ssdt-and-visual-studio-2012-data)

They do shed some light on my scenario, but I feel I may be missing something...

The third article above nicely explains a possible way to deploy database versions including schema and data... but is oriented to deploying to production.

I am looking to streamline deploying DBProj's to Developer DB instances , test, staging and production.(ALL are SQL2012 Std. Edition)

on the developer instances, they may be a few versions off... we have contractors who leave and it may be a couple of dev cycles before a new contractor tries to deploy.

Also, how do you get the schema on the target to clean up itself? I know we can turn off the restrictions to remove schema objects, but on the developer workstation instances the logins are different that other environments and we do not want those deleted!!! The second article has some clues to this but does not work when I tried it. We have one application role across all environments and depending on the environment the right login is placed in there.

I have a sense I may have to propose changing the our schema, which may not fly well the the other leads.

I would appreciate hearing from anyone who has a tried and true process in place that can cover seamless deployment to the 4 environments described above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [Deployment Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/) and [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) from Red Gate (full disclosure - I work for Red Gate).

The approach these two products use for keeping development environments in sync is:

- Developers edit a local database to make their changes (or all edit a shared DB across they whole team)
- Developers can then synchronized the database to an existing source control repository (e.g. SVN/Git/TFS) using SQL Source Control
- Other team members can update their databases from the repository, and changes are applied to their local database.

Deployment Manager works with a CI server to allow the automated deployment of any version of the database to a set of predefined environments.  For example you might want an automated deployment to an integration environment after every commit.  Deployments out to test/staging/production environments are then push button deployments when required.

Under the hood it's the Red Gate SQL Compare comparison technology to compare the versioned database state to the target database state.  This means that any development database can be updated to the latest state, even if it is much older than the head revision, or a new member joining the team.

You can include filters within the packages/repository which will exclude certain objects (for examples users, roles, keys, specific schemas).  This means that you can deploy the same version/package to each environment, and it won't interfere with these objects.

My colleague has just written a [great intro blog post with some videos](http://thefutureofdeployment.com/automate-sales/) if you're interested in more info.